# how to keep a modal popup open after postback

Tags: asp.net, popup, postback, modalpopupextender, webusercontrol

```
//this is my interface

 public interface IPopupGrid 
 {
     void PopupClosed(string key);
     void PopupGridPageChanging(string key);
     void PopupFilterButtonClicked(string key);
     void PopupOkButtonClicked(string key);
     void PopupGridSorting(string key);
 }

//this is the class that implements the interface
//on buton click this loads a grid in modal popup extender
public partial class CustomerChargesMaster : IPopupGrid
{
    public void PopupClosed(string key)
    {
        if (key == "Customer")
            CloseCustomerPopup();
    }

    public void PopupGridPageChanging(string key)
    {
        if (key == "Customer")
            ShowCustomerPopup();
    }

    public void PopupFilterButtonClicked(string key)
    {
        if (key == "Customer")
            ShowCustomerPopup();
    }

    public void PopupOkButtonClicked(string key)
    {
        if (key == "Customer")
            CustomerSelected();
    }

    public void PopupGridSorting(string key)
    {
        if (key == "Customer")
            ShowCustomerPopup();
    }

    private void CloseCustomerPopup()
    {
        CustomerPopupExtender.Hide();
    }

    private void ShowCustomerPopup()
    {
        CustomerPopupExtender.Show();
    }

    protected void SelectCustomerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerPopup.CssClass = "";
        CustomerPopupGrid.GridMode = PopupGridMode.SingleSelect;
        CustomerPopupGrid.LoadPopupControl("Customer", this);

        CustomerPopupExtender.Show();
    }

    private void CustomerSelected()
    {
    }
}

//code inside user control
public partial class GenericPopupGrid : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public void LoadPopupControl(string key, IPopupGrid caller)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            return;

        _key = key;
        ViewState["PopupGridKey"] = key;

        _caller = caller;
        //Session["Caller"] = caller;

        listModel = ModelFactory.GetPopupGridModel(_key);

        if (listModel == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        PopupHeaderLabel.Text = listModel.GridTitle;

        BindGenericPopupGridView();
        GenericPopupGridView.BottomPagerRow.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void FilterOkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //calling the caller class method to keep the popup open
        _caller.PopupOkButtonClicked(_key);
    }
}
```

I have a web user control with grid which I use to load different data depending upon the key passed
This is called as a popup using modal popup extender from a aspx page

Now doing any postback will close the grid 
so i am using the interface to call the method in the caller page, which will keep the popup open
but this is not working as intended

If i add an EventHandler in the UserControl and attach a method in the aspx page then the popup remains open

Is there any other easier way to do this? I do not want to write the code to attach a method to even handler and the method itself in all the aspx pages that calls the popup.

Code is as above

Comment: One solution you might consider: don't do a full postback. Use ajax to do a partial postback so that the full page never reloads. An UpdatePanel (as unoptimized as the control is) is one approach...

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, I believe even the UpdatePanel has issues if the modal is within the update panel.

Comment: Hey Lynn, 

My grid is already inside the update panel. Also the textbox and the filter button. So I guess I am already making a partial post back.

Also it works when I use the EventHandler approach but not when I use the Interface approach.

Comment: Have you tried UpdateMode="Conditional"? That way you gain a little more control as to what needs to be updated. Just a thought.